# Воспроизведение тех audio которые выбраны через input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть большое количество audio и checkbox-ы возле них. Если checkbox выбран, то audio должно воспроизводится, если не выбран, то audio на паузе. Допускается одновременное воспроизведение нескольких audio.

Нашел вот такой скрипт, но он был заточен под выбор одного audio по id. Я решил поправить - прописал getElementsByClassName, но не тут то было :)

Можете помочь поправить скрипт? Можно на js, можно на jquery, верстку тоже можно менять.

```js
var shum = document.getElementsByClassName("shum");
var isPlaying = false;
function toggleShum() {
 isPlaying ? shum.pause() : shum.play();
};
shum.onplaying = function() {
 isPlaying = true;
};
shum.onpause = function() {
 isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="ogon" onClick="toggleShum()">
<audio controls loop class="shum" src="ogon.mp3"></audio>

<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="kot" onClick="toggleShum()">
<audio controls loop class="shum" src="kot.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Подсмотрите, [как работать с getElementsByClassName](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475466/1475477#1475477) - он возвращает HTML коллекцию. Вам в цикле надо будет проверять item.checked

Comment: Спасибо, но я не смог с этим разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggleShum(box) {
  let player = box.nextElementSibling;
  if (box.checked) player.play();
  else player.pause();
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="ogon" onClick="toggleShum(ogon)">
<audio controls loop class="shum" src="ogon.mp3"></audio>

<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="kot" onClick="toggleShum(kot)">
<audio controls loop class="shum" src="kot.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно 